# In this problem, A(x) and B(x) are two predicates over the same domain.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

For each of the statements below, state whether it is true or false. If true, explain why each of its directions → and ← is true. If false state which direction is false and give a counterexample.

(a) ∀x (A(x) ∨ B(x)) ↔ ∀xA(x) ∨ ∀xB(x)

(b) ∀x (A(x) ∧ B(x)) ↔ ∀xA(x) ∧ ∀xB(x)

(c) ∃x (A(x) ∨ B(x)) ↔ ∃xA(x) ∨ ∃xB(x)

(d) ∃x (A(x) ∧ B(x)) ↔ ∃xA(x) ∧ ∃xB(x)

I am stuck on this question. From reasoning it out via sentences, I believe that the correct (or true) arrows for each of the statements are:

(a) Left

(b) Left

(c) Right

(d) Both

How should I be approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b and c both directions hold true ...

b: if everything has both properties $A$ and $B$, then obviously everything has property $A$, and everything has property $B$, ... and vice versa.

c: if there is something that has either property $A$ or $B$, then if that thing has property $A$, then there is something with property $A$, and if that thing has property $B$, then there is something with property $B$. So, either there is something with property $A$, or there is something with property $B$

Going the other way around: Assume that either there is something with property $A$, or something with property $B$. Well, in both cases there would then be something woth either property $A$ or $B$

For a, you are right: only the left direction holds: assume that either everything has property $A$, or everything has property $B$. In both cases, everything has either property $A$ or property $B$. For a counterexample against going right: take as the domain all integers, and let $A(x)$ be '$x$ is even', and let $B(x)$ be '$x$ is odd'

For d, going to the right holds: if there is something with both properties $A$ and $B$, then gclearly there is something (namely that very thing) with property $A$, and there is something (again, that very thing) that has property $B$. For a counterexample going left, see above counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. For clarification on (c) you said that both directions hold true. However, and please correct me if I am wrong, the statement says, for example, "there is a student that passed class A, or class B", which does not sound the same as "there is a student that passed class A, and there is a student that passed class B". Can you clarify this for me please?

Comment: @Maxxie Right .. there is a disjunction on both sides, so you dealing with "or", rather than "and" .... so what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I be approaching this problem?

You should have a *reason* for the answers you have given.  You just need to express your rational.

Eg: you have stated you believe $∀x\,(A(x) ∨ B(x)) ↔ ∀x\,A(x) ∨ ∀x\,B(x)$ is only valid for a Left conditional ($\gets$).   However, why do you think this is so?

---

If all are one *or* all are the other, then anything is *one or the other*.

However, it is possible to have all be one or the other without everything being one, or everything being the other.

---

The first can be demonstrated with a simple proof by cases, but you were not asked for this.

The second can be justified with a counter example. An interpretation where the conditional is not true.  vis:

> Consider the domain of natural numbers with $A$ interpreted as "is odd" and $B$ as "is even".
>
>  Well every natural number is either odd or even, but not all natural numbers are odd and not all natural numbers are even.
>
>  So $\forall x~(A(x)\vee B(x)$ does not entail that $\forall x~A(x)\vee\forall x~B(x)$.